# Compute Engine won't let me login

Tags: google-compute-engine

I changed computers and Compute Engine won't allow me to SSH in, and it won't connect through googles web browser, it just times out. I am effectively locked out of my server.

Any ideas how to get back in?

Comment: did you change your local computer or GCE VM instance? can you connect to Google Cloud Developers Console?

Comment: I changed my local computer, not the VM Instance. Yes, I can connect to Google Cloud Developers Console, but it will not SSH in from the console. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone unfamiliar with gCloud Compute - in order to communicate with your server you have to run through these commands:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/?hl=en_US

Comment: information in that page helped you to fix the issue?